# How do I compare Strings in Java without using compareTo?

Tags: java, string, interface, comparable, compareto

I need to compare two Objects by a string attribute, how can I do this without using the compareTo() method?

My code looks something like this :

```
public int compareTo(className b){
if (b instanceof className){
        className a = (ClassName ) b;
    if (this.stringName==a.stringName) return 0;   
    if (this.stringName > a.stringName) return 1;   // <- How can I know if it this bigger or smaller? Can't use < > operators on strings.
       else 
            return -1;
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use compareTo?

Comment: Well, you can paste in the code from compareTo wherever you need to call it.  Your instructor might not like that, though.

Comment: Or define the equals method of the class to meet your requirements.

Comment: Your use of `instanceof` doesn't make any sense.  Also, you sometimes spell it `className` and then `ClassName`.

Comment: @DavidWallace Well, as fine as `int a = 5; if (a == 5) { a = 5; }`.  Valid but rather pointless.

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  I misread it.  It's currently equivalent to `b != null`, which I guess is a little useful since he's about to dereference it.  But it's not the way this ought to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't use the `==` operator to compare for equality. This operator is for object identity. But it is possible to have two different objects representing the same string. Use the `String.equals()` method instead.

The `String.compareTo()` method is the method of choice to compare strings. It's meant exactly for that.

If you want to implement your own `compareTo()` method, then you can iterate over the individual characters (each of type `char`, see method `String.charAt()`). `char` is a primitive type, so you can use the operators `==`, `<` and `>` to compare two characters. I will not post the whole solution, because you want to learn by trying it by yourself.